# Simulate ECG with JS & Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to simulate a constant heartbeat with JS and Canvas. I have figured most of it out, but my problem is that the line always starts at a different Y position and therefore when I try to clean up the path it looks a little off. I have a JS here, it's one that I modified from another post.

The answer should either be in modifying the PY coordinate somewhere but I can't figure out where. Or in the following line in the loop function.

```
 ctx.clearRect(px,0, scanBarWidth, h);
```

Please let me know if you can help me with this. Thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/tFn66/138/

Comment: Never seen an actual ECG, but to me that looks right.  If you expect the next screenful of waves to line up right on top of the previous screenful, you might have to analyze the data, find the peaks, and then either shift the data to line up right, or adjust the "zoom" factor to fit an exact number of periods onto the screen. If the waveform is always smooth and steady like that, the period could be calculated by the distance between crossings of Y=0 where Y goes from negative to positive.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I was wondering if there's just a way for me to re-set the starting point as soon as the drawn line hits the end of the canvas. So when point X > 500, then the line starts at the front like it is now but you could manually set the height (point Y) to always start at the same position.

Comment: You have a few ways you could make the wave periods line up; perhaps the best way would be to dynamically adjust the X axis so that exactly N periods of the waveform fit on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [source code](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/ecg-line-webcomponent) of this solution. It using a canvas as a backend of draw

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<ecg-line></ecg-line>';
ecgLine((bang) => setInterval(() => bang(), 1000));
```

[image]